# What should be inside the zip file for upload pretrained model into DIGITS?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

I want to upload pretrained model to DIGITS. If I use zip file does not accept file. What should inside the zip file?
How can I upload pretrained model live VGG-19 into DIGITS and use it for different dataset?
How can I fine tune the new model for new dataset which is different in image size and original images?

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading a model from another training job on your server. Look at the contents of that zipfile, and then create a new zipfile with your new content in the same format.

Also, you can just upload the individual files using the form rather than creating a zipfile.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I use manually without any error but when I want to upload zip file I got error.